# shift specific rows from one column to next column

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I have a column X, and I want to split specific rows in other columns.

```
x
76.25
'87.12'
1
345.65
'96.45'
2
78.12
'85.23'
3
35.1
'65.21'
1
```

I want to shift all values with '' to new column Y and all integers to new column sequence. Note all values are text.
desired output is

```
x              y      sequence
76.25       '87.12'     1
345.65      '96.45'     2
78.12       '85.23'     3
35.1        '65.21'     1
```

I have hundreds of rows. I read about shift() to shift values to next column but in this case i don't know row position as there are hundred of rows.is it possible to shift specific values with this criteria? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data are regular and exist each triple you can convert values to numpy array and reshape, then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['x'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,3), columns=['x','y','seq'])
#oldier pandas versions
#df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['x'].values.reshape(-1,3), columns=['x','y','seq'])
print (df1)
        x        y seq
0   76.25  '87.12'   1
1  345.65  '96.45'   2
2   78.12  '85.23'   3
3    35.1  '65.21'   1
```